# GPG client shows ncurses dialog with obscure charset?

Tags: macos, gnupg

I'm trying to generate a GPG key with the command `gpg --gen-key`, but as soon as I'm done entering name and email, GPG shows an ncurse dialog with an obscure charsets (see image).

I'm in macOS, using the built-in system terminal, with GPG program installed through Homebrew.

What happened and how can I fix this? [image: ncurse dialog with an obscure charset from GPG]

Answer (score 0):

Although my system's primary language is English, GPG *pinentry* seems to bypass this setting and select my secondary language instead: Japanese. I managed to fix this problem by adding **English (U.S.)** (in addition to just **English**) in my system preferred language list.